# how to set onClick event on a button inside a datatable in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have seen several working examples in jQuery but none in the context of React. So wanted this specific query raised.

I have a react Component Class which renders a datatable (as in datatables.net). I have added a View Button for each row in the datatable using column:defaultContent of datatable-Options.

I have written a class Method which is supposed to execute when the view Button is pressed.

The embedded HTML in columnDefault Option is

```
                columns: [
                  { "defaultContent":`<button onClick=${this.onView}>View</button>`},
                  { data: "name" },
                  { data: "email" },
                  { data: "mobile", "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>" },
                  { data: "landline", "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>"}
                ]
```

I can see that the Buttons are rendered.

The challenge is to get the onView method to execute with the specific recordId.

Comment: where that id exists can you please explain your scenario

Answer (score 2):

if you want to pass data to the callback function which is bind to onclick of button you can use below mentioned code

```
<button onClick=${() => this.onView(recordId)}>View</button>
```

Comment: it give me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input          I tried using function keyword as well                  { "defaultContent":`<button onClick=${function(){this.onView(_id)}}>View</button>`},

Comment: it also says _id not found during compilation... meaning the _id is a column name of the table which datatable can see but not React.

Comment: try wrapping button in parenthesis 
`{ "defaultContent":(<button onClick=${function(){this.onView(_id)}}>View</button>)}`

Comment: Use `debugger` statement to test weather the id exists or not before that line executed

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
   "columns": [
                   {
                       "data": "Column 1",
                   },
                   {
                       "data": "Column 2",
                   },
                   {
                       "data": "Column 3",
                   },
                   {
                       "data": null,
                       "searchable": false,
                       "orderable": false,
                       "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                           return ''
                       }
                   },
               ], 
 "columnDefs": [
                   {
                       targets: 3,
                       createdCell: (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) =>
                         ReactDOM.render(
                           <button className="btn btn-warning" style={{borderRadius: '30px'}}
                             onClick={changeName}>
                            data
                           </button>, td),
                     } 
               ]
```

```
    const changeName = async (e) => {
        alert('ok')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  columns: [
    { data: 'Column 3' },
    {
      data: null,
      searchable: false,
      orderable: false,
      render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '';
      },
    },
  ],
  columnDefs: [
    { targets: 3, createdCell: (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) => ReactDOM.render(
      <button className="btn btn-warning" style={{borderRadius: '30px'}} onClick={changeName}></button>,
      data,
      td)
    },
  ],
```